# Installation stops

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I had my laptop set up to dual boot: Windows 7/Ubuntu 16.10 and just about had the kinks out (Realtech Wifi is a pain to get working). Suspiciously, I installed ext2explore so Windows could see the Linux part of the drive, and the next time I booted Ubuntu all heck broke out. Fsck failed, suggesting I try e2fsck, I did that and after a minute or two numbers just started flying down the window.  After several minutes of this (which was apparently errors) it completed, but too many files were lost, Ubuntu couldn't start.

I suppose I could play with it and get it all back, but I chose to simply re-install Ubuntu.  Stuck the usb drive in that I'd initially installed from, it came up fine.  Clicked "Installed".  After the usual prompts, it got to the screen where it asks if I want to install updates as it goes along, I checked "Yes", I also checked to install third party software, then clicked to continue.  The little circle thing spun... and spun... and spun.  "Ah!" I said, its trying to use the Realtech wifi and that's unreliable.  Stopped the install and plugged in a regular ethernet cable and started the install again.  Same thing.  Is it getting stuck trying to do something with the messed up partition?  Is there something I can do to just wipe that section clean and get the install to move along?

Comment: Well, this was over a year ago, no answers but thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well, went into the Windows side so I could ensure ext2Fsd is off.  While I was there I used its disk manager and changed the Ubuntu section, and the swap space from "Healthy Partition", to undefined.  Back in Ubuntu, it then loaded nicely.

Now I wonder even more about ext2Fsd.  I'll ask a separate question about it tho.

thanks, Larry